# What should the viewport be set to for some varying page sizes?

Tags: ipad, viewport

i have a page with a body width of 1050px. If I want a *little* amount of space on either side of the page (landscape), so it looks fun, what should i set the viewport meta tag to?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100"/>
  .
```

the above doesn't have the desired effect for me.

And while I'm at it, what would the viewport be for a portrait view? Or does it not matter? (I know how to change the viewport values when an orientation change is detected... but for whatever reason, i can never get it so the stupid resizing effect is cancelled).

And while we're asking questions, can someone just put up what the viewport should be, for an ipad, for the following completely random and not at all related to what i'm doing sizes?

page width of:

```
300px
500px
1000px
1050px
1350px
1800px
```

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is not recommended to set a fixed viewport width...It is best to set it to device-width as follows

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

If you are targetting multiple devices, it is best to use a % based layout and not fxed px values so that your page would scale as per the device viewport.

The iPhone and iPad have a default viewport width of 980px..So if you specify your body a width of 100% or say 90% and use align as center, your page would occupy around 880px with center alignment..